# What is purpose of writing a protocol for even a simple Swift App | Swift

Tags: swift

Wondering what the benefits of writing a protocol for a function are. For example given the following simple example what could be the justification for first creating a protocol that the class conforms to? Is it generally better to always create and conform to a protocol? Better for unit testing?

Are their advantages for doing unit testing when writing ng

```
protocol UserRepositoryProtocol {
    func fetchUser (completion: (User)-> Void)
}
final class UserRepository: UserRepositoryProtocol {
    func fetchUser (completion: (User) -> Void) {
    }
}
```

Comment: here's a link about the benefits of protocols: https://www.raywenderlich.com/6742901-protocol-oriented-programming-tutorial-in-swift-5-1-getting-started

Comment: the link doesn't mention unit tests. you're right that it's another benefit of using protocols, since you're able to test specific parts of the app. say class B uses some logic in class A. If class A conforms to a protocol C and class B uses protocol C's interface, you can inject test object D (that conforms to C) into class B to test different cases.

Comment: I've seen this article, but it still left me wondering if it's good practice to always just use them for structure and readability as well. Thoughts?

Comment: not just structure and readability, protocols enable you to have more reusability in your code (check out how delegates are used in Swift)

Comment: But I guess what I'm wondering is if the function and class will only be used once, does it still make sense to create protocol? (this is for an app not framework)

Comment: this is subjective. imo if you're only going to be using the class once and not going to test it, there isn't a point to creating a protocol for it. if in the future you do need to make it protocol based, it isn't that hard to refactor the code to do so.